# Consulta sql devuelve resultado incorrecto

Tags: sql, postgresql

Hola chicos tengo la siguiente consulta, estoy trabajando en PostgreSQL, y mi base es de una encuesta aplicada a personas de ciertas zonas, basicamente se necesita hacer un analisis que si cuentan con alun tipo de animal esta familia, se ponga el numero uno (como si fuera una casilla de verificacion)

```
select distinct no, FOLIO_FAMILIA, ID_MUNINICPIO, ID_LOCALIDAD,
                PERROS, CERDOS, VACAS, LOROS
                from (
                select distinct row_number() OVER (order by e.FOLIO_FAMILIA, 
                e.ID_MUNICIPIO, e.ID_LOCALIDAD) as No, 
                e.FOLIO_FAMILIA,  e.ID_MUNICIPIO, e.ID_LOCALIDAD,
                count( case when id_caso=1 then 1 else null end) as PERROS,
                count( case when id_caso=2 then 1 else null end) as CERDOS,
                count( case when id_caso=3 then 1 else null end) as VACAS,
                count( case when id_caso=4 then 1 else null end) as LOROS
                from encuesta e , bienes b, zona z
                where e.FOLIO_FAMILIA = b.FOLIO_FAMILIA and
                e.FOLIO_FAMILIA = z.FOLIO    
                and e.ID_MUNICIPIO = '12-15'
                and id_caso in (1,2,3,4) and z.id_zona='12-15-1'        
                group by e.FOLIO_FAMILIA, e.ID_MUNICIPIO, e.ID_LOCALIDAD
                order by e.FOLIO_FAMILIA, e.ID_MUNICIPIO, e.ID_LOCALIDAD) as t1;
```

el resultado se ve así

[image: En lugar de ponerme el uno como lo indiqué en el count case me pone 2]

En lugar de ponerme el uno como lo indiqué en el count case me pone 2

espero me puedan ayudar se los agradezco

Comment: Para estas consultas, debes decir tambien como quieres que se vea, para mi ese resultado se ve correcto, porque hace lo que dice el SQL. vos que resultado queres que salga?

Comment: Como lo indico en mi count case que si esta persona tiene loros o cualquier tipo de animal ponga un uno y me arroja un dos

Comment: Gracias :), pues yo quiero que se muestre un analisis por asi decirlo, que diga si esta familia tiene "perros" que se muestre un uno, y me muestra un dos, cosa que no está bién, porque así pareciera que tiene dos perros, yo lo que quiero es que se asemeje a un check list

Comment: Varias cosas. Mira si mi solucion te sirve. Leiste [ask] <- ACA?? si no, hacelo. Tenes una pregunta con una respuesta sin ser aceptada. no te sirvio? avisale a quien contesto. sirvio? aceptala.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En realidad tu consulta se resuelve mas facil de lo que pensas...

Tu consulta esta bien. El problema que estas teniendo es utilizar un count. La funcino esa cuenta todas las ocurrencias que vengan de filas para esa fila.

Una solucion practica a lo que necesitas, es usar un MAX en lugar de count. como estas devolviendo 0 o 1, si ocurre algun 1, va a devolver 1, y si no, va a devolver 0.

```
select distinct no, FOLIO_FAMILIA, ID_MUNINICPIO, ID_LOCALIDAD,
            PERROS, CERDOS, VACAS, LOROS
            from (
            select distinct row_number() OVER (order by e.FOLIO_FAMILIA, 
            e.ID_MUNICIPIO, e.ID_LOCALIDAD) as No, 
            e.FOLIO_FAMILIA,  e.ID_MUNICIPIO, e.ID_LOCALIDAD,
            MAX( case when id_caso=1 then 1 else 0 end) as PERROS,
            MAX( case when id_caso=2 then 1 else 0 end) as CERDOS,
            MAX( case when id_caso=3 then 1 else 0 end) as VACAS,
            MAX( case when id_caso=4 then 1 else 0 end) as LOROS
            from encuesta e , bienes b, zona z
            where e.FOLIO_FAMILIA = b.FOLIO_FAMILIA and
            e.FOLIO_FAMILIA = z.FOLIO    
            and e.ID_MUNICIPIO = '12-15'
            and id_caso in (1,2,3,4) and z.id_zona='12-15-1'        
            group by e.FOLIO_FAMILIA, e.ID_MUNICIPIO, e.ID_LOCALIDAD
            order by e.FOLIO_FAMILIA, e.ID_MUNICIPIO, e.ID_LOCALIDAD) as t1;
```

Comment: Gracias parce!, me sirvió tu solución :D